# Does Wavwrite or Audiowrite do some Windowing and Fourier Series with some distribution?

Tags: matlab, audio

I have some intuition that it does so. 
Any developer here about the two commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no. It is supposed to just write the raw samples to a wav-file. Do you have anything to backup your intuition? Did you do proper scaling and set the correct number of bits? Maybe you are loosing some of the dynamic range because of this.

According to the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavwrite.html), for floating point input, you have to make sure that your input is between -1 and 1. If it exceeds this, it will clip, which might cause some metallic sound (a low-frequency sine will cause up-conversion to higher harmonics). If the amplitude is much lower and you use a low bit-rate, you might loose some of your signal due to round-off errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My Max(signal) is 1.0110 so I scaled it simply by *sig = sig ./ 1.0110*. I think this can cause some metallic sound. **How should you scale the signal?**

Comment: Haven't used `wavwrite` for a long time, but in one of my old scripts, I see the lines `d = d - median(d);` to center the signal around zero, and then `d = 0.99 * d / max(abs(d));` to make sure it stays within the range -1..1.

Comment: Thank you! Nice tool. What are you using nowadays instead of **wavwrite**?

Comment: Nothing, I just haven't had the need for writing audiofiles lately. But the docs say that wavwrite is deprecated in favor of audiowrite.

Comment: Do you remember this warning **"Warning: Data clipped during write to file:atrialfibrillation.wav"**.? I scale the signal and still keep getting it. Wavwrite seems to cut much my data and need much more it.